# sphinxsearch not returning results in Magento 1.7.0.2

Tags: magento-1.7, catalogsearch, search

We're trying to implement `Sphinx` into `Magento CE 1.7.0.2` via `sphinxsearch` (https://github.com/fheyer/sphinxsearch)

According to the README, it seems like the module has only to be installed and enabled for it to work using Sphinx search; however, the page `/catalogsearch/result/?q=keyword` always returns 'Your search returns no results'.

We've been noting the following:

1. `Sphinx` is correctly working in the terminal and is outputting results
2. If a `print_r($results)` is added within the `prepareResult()` function, we can see the results count from `Sphinx`, which matches the terminal output

It seems like results do not get returned in the `Magento` view that generates the results page - but it does appear that Sphinx is finding results.

Comment: Did you rebuild your search index?

Comment: Looks like the productCollection is not being loaded. Did you try and find the piece of code in the Sphinx extension that is loading the productCollection with the search results?

Comment: @Marius Yes the search index has been rebuilt

Comment: @SanderMangel: Seems like it: https://github.com/fheyer/sphinxsearch/blob/master/app/code/community/Gfe/SphinxSearch/Block/List.php#L68-L69

Comment: Just to be sure, there are no other 3th party extensions overwriting this class to?

Comment: @SanderMangel I've check and it doesn't seems so, I can also edit the file and display debugging informations (which I assume wouldn't have happened if it was being overridden)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a third party module. It also appears to be fixed in a newer version. https://github.com/fheyer/sphinxsearch/issues/3

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug, I've experienced this myself.

Full search terms / key words would return **'Your search returns no results'**

If you perform a search with only 1 character you will receive results. The problem is related to code in Data.php

If you looked in sphinx_catalogsearch_fulltext table in the database, you would find that only the first character for each field.

Upgrading to the latest version will resolve the problem.

If there is a reason for keeping the current version, you can modify the Data.php file as follows:

**Data.php:**

```
89 // The first time we see this add the name to start.
90 $name_attributes[] = $name.' '.$item_value;
```

=>

```
// The first time we see this add the name to start.
 $name_attributes[$key] = $name.' '.$item_value;

63 $name = $index['name'][0]; // Use the configurable product's name
```

=>

```
$name = $index['name'][(int) $entity_id]; // Use the configurable product's name
```

CREDIT: korhov@github